# ¿Cómo separar por miles en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Se necesita hacer que cada 3 números se agregue un punto, por ejemplo, pasar de `10000000` a `10.000.000`.

No sé cómo puedo lograr que se explote cada 3 números el punto. Intenté hacerle una formateada, pero solo sirve si lo escribo.

Me gustaría saber dónde estoy fallando y si alguien me puede orientar de cómo lo puedo hacer.

```js
var waarde;
var bespaar;
      
$("#myRange").on('input', function(){
    waarde = $("#myRange").val();
    $('#woningWaarde').text(waarde);
    $('#woningWaarde2').text(waarde);
});
                
$("#myRange").on('input', function(){

bespaar = Number(((($("#myRange").val())*1000))*0.047);

var a= parseInt(bespaar/1000);
var b= bespaar % 1000;
var strc= b.toString();
var len= strc.length;
if(len === 1){
   B = a + '.00' + strc;
}else if (len === 2){
        B = a + '.00' + strc;
    }else{
         B = a + '.' + strc;
    };
                    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2><span id="woningWaarde">350</span>.000</h2>

<div class="slidecontainer"style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="range" min="350" max="10000" value="350" step = "1" class="slider" id="myRange" list="tickmarks">
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses la librería NumeralJS. Es excelente, de hecho, en varios libros de JavaScript la recomiendan. Te paso link para que veas más al respecto: [http://numeraljs.com/](http://numeraljs.com/)

Comment: @the-breaker Hola, ya amigo ya pude ponerle el codigo, sabes como se puede hacer lo que necesito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregando una función manual para separar puntos en el código queda funcionando de la siguiente manera:

```js
var waarde;
var bespaar;
      
function convertir(numero){
  nnumero = numero+"";
    var op=nnumero.split("").reverse();
    var new1="";
    for(i=0;i<op.length;i++){
      if(i%3==0&&i!=0)
        new1="."+new1;
       new1=op[i]+new1;
    }
    return new1;
    //console.log(new1);
}
                
$("#myRange").on('input', function(){
waarde = $("#myRange").val();             $('#woningWaarde').text(convertir(waarde));
                   $('#woningWaarde2').text(waarde);
                });
                
                $("#myRange").on('input', function(){

bespaar = Number(((($("#myRange").val())*1000))*0.047);



var a= parseInt(bespaar/1000);
                var b= bespaar % 1000;
                var strc= b.toString();
                var len= strc.length;
                    if(len === 1){
                    B = a + '.00' + strc;
                    }else if (len === 2){
                    B = a + '.00' + strc;
                    }else{
                    B = a + '.' + strc;
                    };
                    
                      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h2><span id="woningWaarde">350</span>.000</h2>

<div class="slidecontainer"style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="range" min="350" max="10000" value="350" step = "1" class="slider" id="myRange" list="tickmarks">
  
</div>
```

La función para separar un numero por miles funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
//se envía el numero a convertir
function convertir(numero){ 
   //se convierte el numero a cadena con +"" en nnumero 
   nnumero = numero+"";
   //convertimos la cadena en un array de caracteres con split("")
   //e invertimos el array con reverse() poniendo todo en un nuevo array op       
   var op=nnumero.split("").reverse();
   //en la cadena vacia new1 se pondra el nuevo numero convertido
   var new1="";

   //con esto recorremos el array (op.length = tamaño del numero)
   for(i=0;i<op.length;i++){
       //cada vez que el indice sea multiplo de 3 distinto de 0 agregamos un punto
       if(i%3==0&&i!=0)
           new1="."+new1;
       //concatenamos cada elemento a la cadena new1 para formar el nuevo numero
       new1=op[i]+new1;
   }
   //enviar el nuevo numero
   return new1;
}
```

Por ultimo para aplicarlo en un `<span>` deberas usar `innerHTML` de la siguiente forma:

```
document.getElementById('idelemento').innerHTML=convertir(variable);
```

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo es lo que necesitaba, sera que me puedes explicar un poco lo que haces para aprender?

Comment: @AlvaroMejia, claro, enseguida edito la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias amigo,  me podes ayudar con una ultima cosita, yo tambien quiero hacer lo mismo en otro dos <span> tendria que hacer lo mismo?

Comment: @AlvaroMejia, ahora estoy editando la respuesta, puedes hacer lo mismo con las valores y elementos que gustes con `convertir(variable)`, en el caso de un `<span>` deberas usar `innerHTML("idelemento")`

Comment: que pena molestarte bro te voy a poner el codígo por partes para ver es que me sale un error. al ponerlo acá

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vghbder4/3/

Esto es lo que quiero hacer amigo pero estoy super perdido, mira que cada vez que se mueve el rango varias veces sale numeros diferentes :( @the-breaker me podes echar una mano por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Con esta función puedes formatear un numero por miles en javascript.

```
   function numberWithCommas(x) {  
     var parts = x.toString().split(".");
     parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
     return parts.join(".");
   }
   x = numberWithCommas(2000000000);
```

Comment: Hola, cesar gracias por tu respuesta, que pena contigo sabes como puedo hacer para  que esto funcione con el codigo que e puesto, no encuentro la manera de hacerlo

Comment: Con esto debería funcionar:  function numberWithCommas(x) {  
     var parts = x.toString().split(".");
     parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
     return parts.join(".");
 }
                
$("#myRange").on('input', function(){
    waarde = $("#myRange").val();
waarde = numberWithCommas(waarde)
  $('#woningWaarde').text(waarde);

                });